# Spring Data Mongo MongoDB DBRef lazy initialization

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, lazy-initialization, dbref

I'm using Spring + Spring Data MongoDB.
My model is like this:

```
@Document(collection = "actors")
public class Actor extends DomainEntity {

private String name;
private String surname;
@DBRef(lazy = true)
private List<Class> classes;
```

The other class is pretty generic, so I don't post it.
My problem is that the list "classes" isn't loaded when i try to access it, the attribute remains being some kind of proxy object.
Example:

```
Actor a = actorRepository.findOne(id);
//At this moment classes are a proxy object because of the lazy

//Now I try to load the reference and nothing works
a.getClasses();
a.getClasses().size();
a.getClases().get(0).getAttr();
for(Class g:a.getClasses()){
        g.getAttr();
    }
```

I considered a ton of options, but no way to make it working...

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? What doesn't work? Which exceptions do you get? What would you like to see? If you don't want a proxy for `Class`, don't make it lazy.

Comment: I think he wants to use lazy, but that in a particular case he needs the bean read from the DB to be fully exploited. This is possible?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using `spring-data-mongodb-1.7.0.RELEASE` and I was able to solve this issue by initializing the lazy-loaded collection in its declaration, for instance:

```
@DBRef(lazy = true)
private List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```